# Wikipedia Random Page in Category Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, api, wikipedia

I recently wrote a Python script to generate a random page within a Wikipedia category and its subcategories:

```
"""Generate a random page from a wikipedia category."""
import argparse
import random

import requests

DEBUGGING = False
max_depth = 4
current_depth = 0
header = "Garrett Credi's Random Page Bot(Contact @ gcc@ameritech.net)"
headerVal = {'Api-User-Agent': header}
base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'


def print_debug(str):
    """Print strings if in debug/verbose mode mode."""
    global DEBUGGING
    if(DEBUGGING):
        print("DEBUG: " + str)


def generateRequestsParams(category, mode):
    """Generate the params for requests given a category and a mode."""
    cmtype = ""
    if(mode == "Subcat"):
        cmtype = 'subcat'
    elif(mode == "Subpage"):
        cmtype = 'page'
    params = {
        'format': 'json',
        'action': 'query',
        'list': 'categorymembers',
        'cmtitle': category,
        'cmlimit': 500,
        'cmtype': cmtype
    }
    if(mode == "Pagecats"):
        params = {
            'format': 'json',
            'action': 'query',
            'titles': category,
            'prop': 'categories'
        }
    return params


def wrappedRequest(category, mode):
    """Wrap a request to deal with connection errors."""
    global base_url
    params = generateRequestsParams(category, mode)
    global headerVal
    max_times = 5
    times = 0
    propertyString = 'categorymembers'
    while(times < max_times):
        try:
            r = requests.get(base_url, headers=headerVal, params=params)
            if(mode != "Pagecats"):
                return r.json()['query'][propertyString]
            else:
                for key in r.json()['query']['pages']:
                    return r.json()['query']['pages'][key]['categories']
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            if(times > max_times):
                print_debug("{category} failed too many times ({times}) " +
                            " times. Moving on".format(
                                category=category,
                                times=times
                                )
                            )
                times = 0
                return [category]
            else:
                print_debug("Retrying {category} due to connection " +
                            " error".format(
                                cateogry=category
                                )
                            )
                times += 1


def getSubcategories(category):
    """Get subcategories of a given subcategory."""
    global max_depth, DEBUGGING
    current_depth = 1
    singleStepSubcategories = [category]
    allSubcategories = []
    while(current_depth <= max_depth):
        print_debug("Current tree depth {d}".format(d=current_depth))
        subcategoryTemp = []
        if(len(singleStepSubcategories) == 0):
            break
        for subcat in singleStepSubcategories:
            allSubcategories.append(subcat)
            subcategories = wrappedRequest(subcat, mode="Subcat")
            for cat in subcategories:
                title = cat['title']
                print_debug("{subcat} has subcategory {title}".format(
                                subcat=subcat,
                                title=title
                                )
                            )
                if(title not in allSubcategories):
                    allSubcategories.append(title)
                    subcategoryTemp.append(title)
                else:
                    print_debug("{t} already checked. Moving on".format(
                                                                    t=title
                                                                    )
                                )
        singleStepSubcategories = subcategoryTemp
        current_depth += 1
    return allSubcategories


def saveArray(category, subcats):
    """Save array to file."""
    filename = "{category}_subcats.txt".format(category=category)
    print_debug("Saving to {f}".format(f=filename))
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for cat in subcats:
            f.write(cat+"\n")


def subcategoriesWithoutDuplicates(category):
    """Generate a list of subcategories without duplicates."""
    return set(getSubcategories(category))


def retreiveSubcategoriesFromLocation(category):
    """Get subcategories from file, or generate them from scratch."""
    subCats = []
    fileName = "{category}_subcats.txt".format(category=category)
    try:
        subCatFile = open(fileName, 'r')
        print_debug("Reading from {filename}".format(filename=fileName))
        for count, line in enumerate(subCatFile):
            subCats.append(line.replace("\n", ""))
        subCatFile.close()
    except IOError as ioError:
        print_debug("{fileName} does not exist. Building from " +
                    " network".format(fileName=fileName)
                    )
        subCats = subcategoriesWithoutDuplicates(category)
    return subCats


def checkPageSimilarity(page, subcategories):
    """Check the similarity of page to a list of subcategories.
    Verify if page truly is a subpage of a category.
    """
    global similarityVal
    pageCats = wrappedRequest(page, mode="Pagecats")
    points = 0.0
    # For every supercategory of page, if it is also in subcategories
    # the page is more likely to be a true subpage.
    for cat in pageCats:
        title = cat['title']
        if(title in subcategories):
            points += 1.0
    score = points/len(pageCats)
    print_debug("Score of {p} is {s}".format(p=page, s=str(score)))
    if(score >= similarityVal):
        return True
    return False


def randomPage(category, save, regen, check):
    """Generate a random page from a category."""
    global DEBUGGING
    subCats = []
    read = True
    if(not regen):
        subCats = retreiveSubcategoriesFromLocation(category)
    if(regen or (not read)):
        print_debug("Rebuilding {category}".format(category=category))
        subCats = subcategoriesWithoutDuplicates(category)
    if(save or regen):
        saveArray(category, subCats)
    randomPage = None
    validRandomPage = True
    cat = random.sample(subCats, 1)[0]
    print_debug("Chose category {cat}".format(cat=cat))
    pages = wrappedRequest(cat, mode="Subpage")
    while(not randomPage or not validRandomPage):
        try:
            randomPage = random.choice(pages)
            title = randomPage['title']
            if(check):
                print_debug("Checking " + title)
                validRandomPage = checkPageSimilarity(title, subCats)
                if(not validRandomPage):
                    pages.remove(randomPage)
        except IndexError as a:
            print_debug("{cat} has no pages. Retrying".format(cat=cat))
            cat = random.sample(subCats, 1)[0]
            print_debug("Chose category {cat}".format(cat=cat))
            pages = wrappedRequest(cat, mode="Subpage")
    return randomPage['title']


if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get a random page from a ' +
                                     'wikipedia category')
    parser.add_argument('category', help="The category you wish to get a " +
                        "page from."
                        )
    parser.add_argument('--tree_depth',
                        nargs='?',
                        type=int,
                        default=4,
                        help="How far down to traverse the subcategory tree"
                        )
    parser.add_argument('--similarity',
                        nargs='?',
                        type=float,
                        default=.5,
                        help="What percent of page categories need to be " +
                        "in subcategory array. Must be used with -c/--check")
    parser.add_argument("-s",
                        "--save",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="Save subcategories to a file for quick re-runs"
                        )
    parser.add_argument("-r",
                        "--regen",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="Regenerate the subcategory file"
                        )
    parser.add_argument("-v",
                        "--verbose",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="Print debug lines"
                        )
    parser.add_argument("-c",
                        "--check",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="After finding page check to see that it truly " +
                        "fits in category"
                        )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print_debug(str(args.check))
    DEBUGGING = args.verbose
    max_depth = args.tree_depth
    similarityVal = args.similarity
    if(args.save):
        print_debug("Saving!")
    if(args.regen):
        print_debug("Regenerating!")

    print("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + randomPage("Category:" +
                                                        args.category,
                                                        save=args.save,
                                                        regen=args.regen,
                                                        check=args.check
                                                        )
          )
```

Currently it runs fairly slowly, since it runs over networks via Python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module. Is there any way to make requests more efficient/faster or to get the Wikipedia subcategory tree locally (preferably in a small-ish format)?

I'd appreciate any feedback on the style/structure of my code (e.g. readability, function/variable name, function structure) and any advice on the performance of the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

## General

1. In `print_debug()`, you don't have to use the `global` keyword to refer to `DEBUGGING`. If the Python interpreter can't find the name `DEBUGGING` locally, it will then search for it globally. If it still can't find it, a `NameError` is raised. The only two reasons to use `global` are:

   1. When you have a local and a global variable with the same name, and you explicitly want to refer to the global variable;
   2. In local scope, when you need to (re)assign to a global variable.
2. In `print_debug()`, you're shadowing the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str). To avoid shadowing a variable, by convention, you should add a trailing underscore (as in `str_`). If you find that ugly, you can also spell it out, or abbreviate further: `string` or `s` (the former is more desirable).
3. You don't need parentheses around `if`-statements and `while`-statements.
4. The idiomatic way of checking if a container is empty in Python is to directly use it in an `if`-statement, in this fashion:

   ```
   if not container:
       # Container is empty
   ```

   ... this works because a container's `__bool__()` method returns `True` if it is not empty, and `False` otherwise.
5. When catching an exception, if you don't need access to the exception instance itself, you should leave out the `as ...` part.
6. If you do need access to the exception instance, most people use:

   ```
   except <exception type> as exc:
   ```

   ... or:

   ```
   except <exception type> as err:
   ```
7. The following:

   ```
   if <boolean expression>:
       return True
   return False
   ```

   ... can be shortened to:

   ```
   return <boolean expression>
   ```
8. In `randomPage()`, the following:

   ```
   if(regen or (not read)):
   ```

   ... can be simplified to become:

   ```
   if regen or not read:
   ```
9. Avoid global variables. They are a telltale sign of a design problem in your code. Global constants are acceptable, but non-constant global variables can cause all kinds of trouble:

   1. It's hard to track where they are being used and modified. This problem becomes very prominent when using threads;
   2. [Loading a global variable is more costly than loading a local one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590209/8101215);
   3. If you design an API and have lots of global variables floating about, when someone performs a wildcard import, their global namespace will be cluttered.
10. Generally, if you find yourself doing this:

    ```
    my_list = []
    for x in some_container:
        if some_condition_applies(x):
            my_list.append(x)
    ```

    ... a list comprehension would be a good fit:

    ```
    my_list = [x for x in some_container if some_condition_applies(x)]
    ```

    A list comprehensions is shorter and [*often* faster than its `for`-loop counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/8101215).
11. Debug messages should be sent to stderr, not stdout:

    ```
    import sys

    ...

    print("DEBUG: " + str, file=sys.stderr)
    ```

### PEP-8

PEP-8 is the name of [the official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You violated it a couple of times:

12. Your indentation is all over the place. Sorry, but it had to be said. Take this excerpt:

    ```
                        print_debug("{t} already checked. Moving on".format(
                                                                        t=title
                                                                        )
                                    )
    ```

    ... isn't that hard to read? Something like this would be much easier on the eyes:

    ```
    print_debug(
        "{t} already checked. Moving on".format(t=title)
    )
    ```

    ... or this:

    ```
    print_debug("{t} already checked. Moving on".format(
        t=title)
    )
    ```

    Ultimately, it's up to you. PEP-8 also lists some examples of acceptable styles.<sup>1</sup>
13. Use `snake_case` for function and variable names. Only use `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` for constants.<sup>2</sup>
14. Don't mix single and double quotes. I prefer double quotes, because they're less likely to cause clashes with quotation marks in flowing text.<sup>3</sup>
15. Limit the line length to 79 characters.<sup>4</sup>

### Docstrings

16. Good job on adding docstrings to your functions and to the module itself. Most people (including me) often can't bring up the effort to add documentation, but you have! :) If you want to help yourself understand the code in 6 months' time, or if you want to publish this as an API, you should be a bit more thorough, for instance by adding information about:

    - What arguments the function takes, what type they should be, and exactly what they convey;
    - The return type of the value;
    - Any special cases the caller should be aware of.

    There's even a style guide for docstrings: [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

## Performance

I don't currently have the time to do a full review on performance, but I suggest you run [a profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see where you can optimize. The problem is very likely to be I/O-bound, but the debugging can have a noticable performance hit.

If you want to squeeze a little bit of extra speed out of `requests`, you can use a [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object, which:

> ... [omitted] will use urllib3's connection pooling. So if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase ... [omitted]

## References

1 [PEP-8: Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

2 [PEP-8: Function and variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

3 [PEP-8: String Quotes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes)

4 [PEP-8: Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)